# Add Navigation Property when column already exists

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

How can I add a navigation property to my context, when the corresponding column has already been created in the database from a previous migration?

For example: A lady has many cats.  I want to add a `LadyId` property to the `Cats` class, but a `LadyId` column already exists in the `Cats` table. This `LadyId` column was created in a previous migration to accommodate the `Cats.Lady` navigation property.

DB:

```
Lady Table
--------------
Id    Name

Cats Table
--------------
Id    LadyId    FurColor
```

Classes:

```
public class Lady {
    public Id {get; set;}
    public Name {get; set;}
    public List<Cat> Cats {get; set;}
}

public class Cat {
    public Id {get; set;}
    public Lady Lady {get; set;}
    //I want to add a LadyId property here
}
```

So far, I've tried...

- **Adding the property**: Error: "The model backing the 'Context' context has changed..."
- **Adding a migration to update the DB**: This creates a migration, but it just renames the column to `LadyId1`, which is pointless.  The DB should remain the same, I just want to add a Navigation Property.
- **Commenting out code in migration `Up` and `Down` methods to try and "trick" the migration table into having the correct hash to match my context.**  This throws an error "Invalid column name 'EmployeePerformanceReview_id1"

Comment: Are you using Automatic migrations? Usually the first error happens when this is enabled.

Comment: When you add the property, do you explicitly map it as foreign key for the `Lady` property?

Comment: Hi, usually I go with your third approach (empty migration) in such cases (changing the model but not the schema). EmployeePerformanceReview_id1 looks unrelated, are you sure you haven't changed anything else? Or is it just your original error message not translated to Cats and Ladies? Could you add the contents of your context's OnModelCreating() method (you seem to be using the fluent API as I see no attributes)?